# Textarea formatting lost during copy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem:**
After formatting text in a textarea, formatting is lost when copying to another textarea, whether by code or by mouse copy through ctrl-drag.

**Details:**
To prove the issue, I have a simple html page with no CSS, and a javascript function that formats the text by removing line breaks, using . I copy text from Notepad to my webpage's `textarea1`. I run the javascript function. This function replaces all carriage returns with "". The function runs correctly, with no errors. After running, all carriage returns have been removed from the text in `textarea1`. I can confirm they've been removed by running a function that copies the text from `textarea1` to `textarea2`.

But, the weirdness comes next. After formatting `textarea1`, when I select all text and ctrl-drag (to copy) the text to `textarea2`, the original text is copied, with carriage returns back in place exactly where they were at before. The same happens if I copy-paste. What's going on?

**Setup:**
Win 7 machine, running IE9.

**Code:**
HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text Editor</title>
    <!--scripts-->
    <script src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="text_edit_test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Service Notes Text Editor</h1>
    <textarea id="textarea1" cols="60" rows="11"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="button" id="buttonRemoveCR">Format Text</button>
    <button type="button" id="buttonCopyText">Copy Text</button>
    <br>
    <textarea id="textarea2" cols="60" rows="30"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

... and javascript...

```
// make sure doc ready first
$(document).ready(function(){
//format Text
$("#buttonRemoveCR").click(function(){
    var myText = "";
    var myTextRes = "";
    myText = $("#textarea1").html();
    //remove all char returns
    myTextRes = myText.replace(/\r/, "");
    //change text in textarea1 so no carriage returns
    $("#textarea1").html(myTextRes);
});

//copy Text
$("#buttonCopyText").click(function(){
    var myText = "";
    myText = $("#textarea1").html();
    $("#textarea2").html(myText);
});
});
```

Comment: [A fiddle for everybody](http://jsbin.com/palig/1/edit) (personally I don't understand the question).

Comment: @dystroy: sorry, the question is, why is the formatting displayed correctly, but then lost when copying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// make sure doc ready first
$(document).ready(function(){
//format Text
$("#buttonRemoveCR").click(function(){
    var myText = "";
    var myTextRes = "";
    myText = $("#textarea1").val();
    //remove all char returns
    myTextRes = myText.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '')
    //change text in textarea1 so no carriage returns
    $("#textarea1").val(myTextRes);
});

//copy Text
$("#buttonCopyText").click(function(){
    var myText = "";
    myText = $("#textarea1").val();
    console.log(myText);
    $("#textarea2").val(myText);
});
});
```

Comment: I noticed the regex value has been changed, and I'm curious why you chose to modify it it your answer?

Comment: Different systems can use different way to put line breaks. It can be 3 options: 1) \r\n 2) \r 3)\n

Comment: +1 to explain a secondary but important issue of the need to change the regex, otherwise simply replacing .html with .val will not work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `x.val()` to get the content of textarea `x` and `x.val(text)` to set the contents of textarea `x` -- textareas ignore their inner HTML.

Comment: +1 The innerHTML property value isn't updated when the value change.

Comment: @dystroy OK. I wanted to give a clear solution, so here you go!

Comment: replacing .html with .val in the question seems to break the formatting function. no errors, but the carriage returns are not removed.